# Average L1 norm (normalized by input features) in Densenet

Tags: python, neural-network, convolution

I am implementing a network. Densenet[3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.06993) paper made a heatmap of layer dependency (as shown in image
[image: Layer dependency heatmap]

they describe it as one pixel in heatmap is the average L1 norm of weights normalized by a number of input features. 
[image: image description]

Can anybody explain this description in detail? how can this be  calculated if I have 3x3x3x40 weight matrix size (3x3 is filter size, 3 is input channels and 40 refers to the output channels) it will be calculated to one pixel of the heatmap

Answer (score 1):

I think that means only compute the means of related kernels of filters with the source layer and normalize it . 
For example , if  input feature map is h*w*16 and second 8 channel from source layer,  and the conv kernel is 3*3*16*16  so the related kernel is 3*3*16*8 .

- you can see this pic for more detail about [conv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg4Np.png)